# React.js: How to access URL params in Private Route

Tags: reactjs, redux, routes, frontend

I decided to make some private routes which only logged in users can access, but I stumbled upon a problem where I don't know how to send the URL params (article id). I did it in a "normal" route, but now I am stuck. Here is my render method:

```
 render() {
let auth = store.getState().auth.isAuth;
return (
  <Fragment>
    <Header />
    <Route path="/" exact={true} component={HomePage} />
    <Route path="/articles/:id" component={ArticleSinglePage} />
    <ProtectedRoute auth={auth} path="/profile/:id/articles" component={MyArticles} />
    <ProtectedRoute path="/edit/:id/" component={EditArticle} />
    <ProtectedRoute path="/writeArticle" component={WriteArticle} />
  </Fragment>
);
```

}

Here is my ProtectedRoute component:

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({auth, component:Component, match, ...rest}) => {
  return (
    <Route {...rest}
    render = { () => auth ? (<Component/>) : <Redirect to="/"/>} />
  )
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify in the private routed component like `MyArticles` how you are trying to access url params? Are you using the props exposed by react-router-dom `Route` in the actual component to get route params? Or are you expecting a custom prop that you manually pass to the component in the render prop? Are you using withRouter()? This data may already be available on the rendered component beacuse you are doing `{...rest}`, but it dpends on how you are trying to get those props. As in https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/route-props

Answer (score 0):

I might try passing `match` as a prop to `Component`: `<Component match={match} />`.

So, `ProtectedRoute` becomes:

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({auth, component:Component, match, ...rest}) => {
  return (
    <Route {...rest}
    render = { () => auth ? (<Component match={match}/>) : <Redirect to="/"/>} />
  )
}
```